# Can you see who is watching a repo on GitHub?

Tags: github, github-pages

It looks like there is an API call to view the users that watch a repo from [GithubDeveloper]:(https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/watching/#list-watchers)

```
List watchers
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/subscribers
```

Is there any way to see this list on the site? 
Am I interpreting the API correctly? Is watching equal to subscribing?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

When on a repo's page, you'll see links on the right side in the "About" column that give you this information:

[image: Repo Watchers]

Or go to this URL directly:

```
https://github.com/{user}/{project}/watchers
```

Comment: @DougR same for Star and Fork, just click the number next to each button (the other 2 numbers NOT highlighted in red in my image)

Comment: Yes I see. Thank you. I'll mark this question as correct as soon as I can (12 minute rule). This was an unasked question about GitHub, trivial though it may be. I'd appreciate an upvote.

Comment: Abststracting this just a bit, can you see who upvoted questions and answers in StackOverflow? I got into a weird debate with someone because they thought I downvoted them (when I did not).

Comment: Ha, so any other question, I should be able to check?

Comment: If so, how? I'm tring to right now on another question

Comment: Or is this a feature that comes with reputations?

Comment: It is a feature that comes with being a developer at Stack Overflow. ;)

Comment: This has recently changed. Now watchers are accessible from an "About" section in the right column.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Haney.  Please consider updating it with the correct information after Github made changes.  See @simleo's comment.

Answer (score 44):

This has recently changed. Now watchers are accessible from an "About" section in the right column.

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, there is now a link "$x watching".